# EF Code First Multiple entities to same table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am interested in how I can map two entities to same table, by using code first. Here's an example:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Age { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Age { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I'm fed up with building repositories. I want to map all possible models for configuration portal, user portal, other services in modelbuilder and just use DbContext for everything. I want to set User class as top of the hierarchy and a class that builds the database, while all other models should just be there for various applications.

I don't want to use automapper. I've also done fair amount of manual coding which just wasted my time, and every single modification requires me to go back to repository and recode - which annoys me.

I've tried to use this in modelbuilder, but it warns me that hierarchy is not valid:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(p => { p.ToTable("Users"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserViewModel>().Map(p => { p.ToTable("Users"); });
    }
```

Also keep in mind that I'm not trying to achieve "Table splitting". I don't want my table to be split in two entities, I want rather to have all columns nullable, except one with primary key, and allow different applications/web services/web portals to populate as much data as they've been granted access for.

Thanks for all the tips :)

Comment: Take a look at the generic repository pattern. All you need is a single base repository for all your entities. I feel your pain, I used stub out a repository for every entity until I discovered the generic repositories pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. One table = one entity (except advanced mappings like mentioned table splitting and TPH inheritance). View model is not and entity. It is just view on data / projection so handle it that way. You will always work with User and project user to view model you need:

```
var view = from u in context.Users
           select new UserViewModel
              {
                  UserId = u.UserId,
                  Name = u.Name,
                  Age = u.Age
              };
```

Make this as reusable method returning `IQueryable<UserViewModel>` and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I was doing projection before, but not with reusable method. Your idea both helped me + my code now looks much more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: The database still returns unnecessary data though so not brilliant. I was hoping to remove some varchar(max)s from a query using this method but it still returns all that data and just removes the properties in the web app

Comment: Which is fine for this scenario but warning others concerned about performance

Comment: @BritishDeveloper: Projection doesn't load unnecessary columns if correctly used. Are you sure that you don't call `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` before doing projection?

Comment: Yes, certain ToList() is the very last thing called. Have you checked in SQL Profiler to make sure you see exactly what is running in the db? I'd be interested if I am doing something weird I can fix to remove superfluous data using this method

Comment: I beg your pardon, you made me investigate further and it was a bizarre consequence of my (not-so) fancy selector static field of type Func<,> rather than Expression<Func<,>>